# Why does ReadWriteMemory return two different addresses?

Tags: python, pointers, memory, 64-bit, ctypes

I am trying to get the 64-bit memory address of a variable, using a pointer created with CheatEngine.
Here are the pointers:

```
from ReadWriteMemory import ReadWriteMemory
from numpy import int64
import win32api
import win32process
import win32con
import ctypes as c

rwm = ReadWriteMemory()

process = rwm.get_process_by_name("NAME.exe")
process.open()

def get_process_by_namee(process_name):
    """Finds the process id of the given
    process name and returns the process id and its base address."""

    process_name = process_name.lower()

    # Enumerate all processes
    processes = win32process.EnumProcesses()

    for process_id in processes:
        # If process_id is the same as this program, skip it
        if process_id == -1:
            continue

        # Try to read the process memory
        try:
            h_process = win32api.OpenProcess(win32con.PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | win32con.PROCESS_VM_READ, True, process_id)

            # Try to read the modules of the process
            try:
                # modules is an array of base addresses of each module
                modules = win32process.EnumProcessModules(h_process)

                for base_address in modules:
                    # Get the name of the module
                    name = str(win32process.GetModuleFileNameEx(h_process, base_address))

                    # Compare it to the name of your program
                    if name.lower().find(process_name) != -1:
                        return process_id, base_address
            finally:
                win32api.CloseHandle(h_process)
        except:
            pass

# this is the prefered imagebase + specific offset for the variable
baseaddress =  c.c_uint64(0x00007FF7BBE80000 + 0x0218F138)

boostPointer1 = process.get_pointer(c.c_uint64(baseaddress), offsets=[0x3F0, 0x0, 0x60, 0x178, 0x0, 0xC0, 0xA8C])
boostPointer2 = process.get_pointer(c.c_uint64(0x1B8CC0FFC24))

boost_count = process.read(boostPointer1)

print (boost_count)
```

When i create a pointer in CheatEngine with the offsets and stuff of boostPointer1, i get the address, which i put into boostpointer2 (0x1B8CC0FFC24)
However, when i read boostPointer1 and boostPointer2, i get different results, leading to a different memory spot being read. Why does boostPointer1 return a different Pointer, than boostPointer2, and how can this be fixed?

Comment: What is *process.get\_pointer*?

Comment: Make a [mcve] and you May get some answers to your questions

Comment: @MarkTolonen my bad, i changed it

Comment: The math doesn't add up.  0x00007FF7BBE80000 + 0x0218F138 != 0x1B8CC0FFC24

Comment: @MarkTolonen Yes, I put the wrong address in there, because there were mutliple variables with the same value, but its certainly not 2700, like boostPointer1 becomes